# como deixar um embed com width e height fixo responsivo?

Tags: php, html, iframe, layout-responsivo, embed

Alguém sabe como deixar este embed responsivo, não consigo pois tras um width e um height fixo?

```
<iframe src="//vshare.io/v/f171731/width-470/height-305/" width="470" height="305" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe> <p>
```

Comment: Por favor, faça uma pergunta completa da forma que seja simples sua dúvida.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar embed-responsive se estiver usando bootstrap ou esse css:

```
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper object,
.videoWrapper embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Seguindo essa ideia você vai usar:

```
<div class="videoWrapper"><embed ...>
```

Answer (score -1):

poderia criar uma classe que iria conter o embed, e definir o valor que quer (altura e largura) depois iria colocar overflow:hidden, e no embed, colocaria centralizado na div pai.
sei que nao é a melhor forma, porque iria cortar parte do embed, mas tem outra forma que é alterar no elemento por estilo em linha (aquele `<embed style="width: tal; height: tal;">` ), em linha porque é o que nao irá sofre alterações externas, pois é aplicado diretamente no local